# How to show soft input keyboard (gboard) in GIF search Mode

Tags: android, gboard

i've seen in some apps that it is possible to order Gboard to force open or focus into an EditText but when keyboard opens it is not the usual keyboard, it opens in a "search gifs" or "random GIF suggestion" mode. It is usually used in some apps to display an "Insert GIF" button next to the edittext. Here's an example:

**Keyboard opens as usual when you click on the EditText. Please note the presence of the "GIF" button next to the camera button.**

[image: Normal]

[image: GIF Mode]

**Keyboard opens in GIF search mode, just by tapping the "GIF" button mentioned earlier.**

Any ideas on how to trigger this specific soft keyboard mode programmatically? I've been reading a lot of info but not able to find any similar question asked before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this did not have anything to do with the keyboard itself. The GIF button just opens a recyclerview full of third party trending gifs withdrown via an API call (eg: giphy/tenor) which sits on top of the keyboard.